# Receiving error(null) and auth object GTMOAuth2Authentication in ios

Tags: ios

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
               error: (NSError *) error
{
   //NSString *anAccessToken = auth.accessToken;
   // NSLog(@"acess token is...%@",anAccessToken);
   NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
   NSLog(@"Received Access Token:%@",auth);

   if (error)
        {
    // Do some error handling here.
        }
   else
   {
    [self refreshInterfaceBasedOnSignIn];
   }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> 2015-08-26 13:11:13.808 sighngoogle[1704:82510] Received error (null)
>   and auth object GTMOAuth2Authentication 0x7fc6c2d88d80:
>   {accessToken="ya29.2wGSNOR6GJ3akCxwXODt8UR2IgK7xy7gESO7rpKiCfttUrDl4EVZFst8P8bXWUorsGtf",
>   refreshToken="1/cL_qccP5UxkP1gszIG8QZUIN0tzjWWzlYWtoBgy0oTo",
>   expirationDate="2015-08-26 08:41:12 +0000"} 2015-08-26 13:11:13.809
>   sighngoogle[1704:82510] Received Access Token:GTMOAuth2Authentication
>   0x7fc6c2d88d80:
>   {accessToken="ya29.2wGSNOR6GJ3akCxwXODt8UR2IgK7xy7gESO7rpKiCfttUrDl4EVZFst8P8bXWUorsGtf",
>   refreshToken="1/cL_qccP5UxkP1gszIG8QZUIN0tzjWWzlYWtoBgy0oTo",
>   expirationDate="2015-08-26 08:41:12 +0000"}

When I run button is disappearing from screen and I'm getting this error

Comment: Please format your code and clarify your question so that it would be easier for people to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks or your suggestion..